# Locale change to time_ago_in_words not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the default time_ago_in_words function to use 1min instead for 1minute for example.

I came across the following but it doesn't seem to change anything. Inside en.yml

```
en:
   datetime:
       distance_in_words:
          x_minutes:
            one: "1 min"
            other: "%{count} min"
```

any clues?

Comment: Where is your `en.yml` located? Just to double check.

Comment: its in config/locales/en.yml @jdgray

Comment: It's the correct way, seems Rails is not picking it up. It should not be needed but have you restarted the server?

Comment: @Iceman yes i have, i know its quite strange

Comment: Are there perhaps two instances of this code in the en.yml file overriding this one?

Comment: @Iceman nop in my en.yml i have only 2-3 things so its easy to see if i have overlaps, and i don't.. can you try on a sample rails app yourself and see if it works?

Comment: Yeah sure, the code works fine for me

Comment: Do you have any other locale files? You could try removing one semicolon from the file, just to introduce a syntax error, at least to see if the file is being used at all.

Comment: I also booted a fresh rails app with no issues. How exactly are you trying to use it?